# apache-camel rabbitmq ssl integration not working

Tags: java, rabbitmq, apache-camel

We are using apache-camel to connect with rabbitmq. Now we are planning to connect rabbitmq using https. I followed steps to enable rabbitmq to https using

https://www.rabbitmq.com/ssl.html.

Now in my code we are using.

```
rabbitmq://host:port/exchange?autoAck=false&autoDelete=false&password=test&prefetchCount=1&queue=testqueue&sslProtocol=TLSv1.2&username=test
```

This works fine if we disable peer verification in rabbimq. But if i want to enable peer verification then i need to pass KeyManager and truststore. Not sure how can pass this details. I can see the documentation say to use connectionFactory as

**To use a custom RabbitMQ connection factory. When this option is set, all connection options (connectionTimeout, requestedChannelMax…​) set on URI are not used**

when i given this as part of query parameter i got below error..

```
ERROR [2020-01-10 19:29:12,030] io.dropwizard.cli.ServerCommand: Unable to start server, shutting down                                                                                                 
! org.apache.camel.NoSuchBeanException: No bean could be found in the registry for: com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory@44f0ff2b of type: com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory                      
! at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.mandatoryLookup(CamelContextHelper.java:173)                                                                                                             
! at org.apache.camel.util.EndpointHelper.resolveReferenceParameter(EndpointHelper.java:326)                                                                                                           
! at org.apache.camel.util.EndpointHelper.resolveReferenceParameter(EndpointHelper.java:308)                                                                                                           
! at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.resolveAndRemoveReferenceParameter(DefaultComponent.java:415)                                                                                              
! at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.resolveAndRemoveReferenceParameter(DefaultComponent.java:394)                                                                                              
! at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQComponent.createEndpoint(RabbitMQComponent.java:62)                                                                                                   
! at org.apache.camel.component.rabbitmq.RabbitMQComponent.createEndpoint(RabbitMQComponent.java:32)                                                                                                   
! at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultComponent.createEndpoint(DefaultComponent.java:116)                                                                                                                  
! at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:631)                                                                                                               
! ... 33 common frames omitted                                                                                                                                                                         
! Causing: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: rabbitmq://host:port/exchangeName?autoAck=false&autoDelete=false&connectionFactory=com.rabbitmq.c
lient.ConnectionFactory%4044f0ff2b&password=test&prefetchCount=1&queue=testQueue&sslProtocol=TLSv1.2&username=test due to: No bean could be found in the registry for: com.rabbitmq.client.Connec
tionFactory@44f0ff2b of type: com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory                                                                                                                                    
! at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:678)                                                                                                               
! at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:80)                                                                                                         
! at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.resolveEndpoint(RouteDefinition.java:219)                                                                                                                  
! at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:112)                                                                                                           
! at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:118)                                                                                                           
! at org.apache.camel.model.FromDefinition.resolveEndpoint(FromDefinition.java:69)                                                                                                                     
! at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.getEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:94)                                                                                                                
! at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1278)                                                                                                                       
! at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:204)                                                                                                                        
! ... 25 common frames omitted                                                                                                                                                                         
! Causing: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1: Route(route1)[[From[rabbitmq://10.65.226.201:5671/preValidat... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: rabbitmq://host:port/exchangeName?autoAck=false&autoDelete=false&connectionFactory=com.rabbitmq.c
lient.ConnectionFactory%4044f0ff2b&password=test&prefetchCount=1&queue=testQueue&sslProtocol=TLSv1.2&username=test due to: No bean could be found in the registry for: com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory@44f0ff2b of type: com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory
```

How can i pass `connectionFactory` to uri in `rabbitmq`.

Comment: Use `#beanId` syntax to lookup the connection factory from registry such as spring or what you may use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass ConnectionFactory object instance we need to do lookup of object, This can be achieved by puting object into registry, Create a registry and put the connection into registry. For details [camel & Rabbitmq Custom ConnectionFactory](https://hexa1.com/camel-rabbitmq-connectionfactory/)

```
    SimpleRegistry simpleRegistry = new SimpleRegistry();
    String beanName = "rabbitConnectionFactory";
    simpleRegistry.put(beanName, connectionFactory);
    CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext(simpleRegistry);
```

Then create rabbitmq url which will refer to connectionFactory.

```
"rabbitmq:/jobProgress?autoAck=false&autoDelete=false&prefetchCount=1&prefetchEnabled=true" +
            "&queue=jobProgress&connectionFactory=#rabbitConnectionFactory";
```